# Import additional namespace as project default in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, resharper

Is there a way to add into the default namespaces that gets added whenever you pick a class template in Visual Studio?

My problem is adding a new class (in my case a C# one), does not include my common library. It's a tremendous productivity hit having to constantly add namespaces of the in-house custom APIs over and over again. The problem has gotten worse over the years due fragmentation. Even the .NET import has grown in size.

I tried Resharper while it helps, it doesn't fully address the problem. I still need to have the exact type name before I can tell it to auto import.

I have also tried using snippets and while nice, creating one isn't straight forward either, and it takes a few extra clicks for every new file.

Creating a new template is also a pain. Not to mention we use all kinds of templates from controllers, to views, to basic classes, interface etc.. We would also need a few versions of each, because each module usually requires 2-3 other namespaces.  Then we need to keep it updated every time there's a major framework release eg. .NET 2.0 project templates didn't have LINQ, now it's on every template. Then we need to keep these templates synched up on all the Dev machines. Bottom line is we don't have the resources for this.

Really I just want to add to the default imports (per project/namespace) that doesn't involve recreating all the major templates out there. Either that or make certain namespace "local" to a given project that I can stop writing a bunch of "using" statements every time I create a new class.

Is there a simpler way about this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can alter the class template files that Visual Studio uses when creating a new type. These templates are located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring
```

The template of interest for your scenario is `GenerateTypeInNewFile`, which consists of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
        <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
            <Header>
                <Title>Generate Type In New File</Title>
                <Description>Snippet for generating a type in a new file</Description>
                <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
                <SnippetTypes>
                    <SnippetType>Refactoring</SnippetType>
                </SnippetTypes>
            </Header>
            <Snippet>
                <Declarations>
                    <Literal Editable="true">
                        <ID>namespace</ID>
                        <Default></Default>
                    </Literal>
                    <Literal Editable="true">
                        <ID>modifiers</ID>
                        <Default></Default>
                    </Literal>
                    <Literal Editable="true">
                        <ID>typekind</ID>
                        <Default>class</Default>
                    </Literal>
                    <Literal Editable="true">
                        <ID>typename</ID>
                        <Default>name</Default>
                    </Literal>
                    <Literal Editable="true">
                        <ID>typebase</ID>
                        <Default></Default>
                    </Literal>
                    <Literal>
                        <ID>linqusing</ID>
                        <Function>CheckMinimumTargetFramework(3.5,
                            using System.Linq;)
                        </Function>
                    </Literal>
                </Declarations>
                <Code Language="csharp">
                    <![CDATA[$end$using System;
                        using System.Collections.Generic;$linqusing$
                        using System.Text;

                        namespace $namespace$
                        {
                            $modifiers$ $typekind$ $typename$ $typebase$
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    ]]>
                </Code>
            </Snippet>
        </CodeSnippet>
    </CodeSnippets>
```

---

The section of interest for you is this `<Code>` section:

```
<Code Language="csharp">
    <![CDATA[$end$using System;using System.Collections.Generic;$linqusing$
        using System.Text;

        namespace $namespace$
        {
            $modifiers$ $typekind$ $typename$ $typebase$
            {
            }
        }
    ]]>
</Code>
```

Add your `using xyz.blah.blah.blah` namespace right after the `using System.Text;`, save and the next class you add should be good to go.

---

> Note: This is going to change how classes are added across all projects in Visual Studio, so beware!

Comment: Karl, that looks great - def better than nothing, but is there a way to use variables that are tied to the project when generating the using statements? I need to customize the default "local" namespaces on at least per project basis.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding a class using ReSharper's insert file feature, you can edit the template that's used by going to ReSharper -> Templates Manager -> File templates. Under the C# section, you can edit the "class" template and add any required using statements at the top. You can use macros to decide what the root namespaces should be, and if the macros don't give you want you want, you can [write a plugin to add a macro](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/4.04+Live+Template+Macros+%28R8%29) that will generated the namespaces how you want:

Comment: That looks very promising. Give me a few days, I will verify your suggestion.